# icecast + Adobe Flash Media Live Encoder

Tags: streaming, adobe, icecast, flashmedialiveencoder

So I am working with a community TV channel to stream their TV station in Audio only formate. I know that they currently use Adobe Flash Media Live Encoder to send a WebTV stream to a provider. What we are discussing is creating an Icecast stream of their TV broadcast.

I am wondering is there a way to take Adobe Flash Media Live Encoder    stream and read metadata and send all that to an Icecast stream either using FFMPEG or other technologies?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have FFmpeg act as an RTMP server which you could connect your encoder to:

```
ffmpeg -listen 1 rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935 …
```

However, I think you'll find it would be better to use FFmpeg in parallel, encoding from the same source.  I'm going to guess that you're not using MPEG-4 and AAC audio on your Icecast stream, so it would be better to encode from the source rather than to transcode already lossy audio/video.

As for metadata, depending on your media format, you'll have to handle that out-of-band with a separate script.